# Mongoose: Can't save nested object to nested model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema set up:

```
var TradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        channel: String,
        trade: {
            tradeid: Number,
            timestamp: Date,
            datetime: Date,
            marketid: Number,
            marketname: String,
            quantity: Number,
            price: Number,
            total: Number,
            type: String
        }
    });

var MarketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String, index: true },
        trades: [TradeSchema]
    });
```

The Trade schema doesn't actually need to have the "trade" property nested like that, but I am getting it from anAPI and for now I want to keep that exactly as I got it.

The problem is, when I take the raw JS object:

```
{
    channel: 'trade.5',
    trade: {
        tradeid: '86554823',
        timestamp: 1425569593,
        datetime: '2015-03-05 10:33:13 EDT',
        marketid: '5',
        marketname: 'FTC/BTC',
        quantity: '957.65001732',
        price: '0.00001210',
        total: '0.01158757',
        type: 'Sell'
    }
}
```

...and I save it...

```
market.trades.push(trade);
market.save(function(err){
    if (err) console.log('Error saving trade to market.');
});
```

...it seems to strip out the 'trade' key, and this is all that gets saved to the db:

```
{ channel: 'trade.5', _id: 54f9e3056e23df1ee3e60327 }
```

Am I missing a validation step, mass-assignment problem, etc?

EDIT: If I set the TradeSchema to just have an Object type, it saves fine:

```
var TradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        channel: String,
        trade: Object
    });
```

Not sure what I would lose since I am new to the Mongo/Mongoose, but it seems like there's probably a downside.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After creating your `Trade` object and before pushing it to `market.trades`, use the `markModified` function, passing the `trade` path to it, like this:

```
trade.markModified('trade');
```

This will tell Mongoose that this path was modified and save it to the DB. This is required for Mixed schema types.

Comment: You can also use it like this way, if you already have model with some changed and nested object: `market.trades.push(trade); market.markModified('trades');
market.save();` It has worked for me like a charm! Ty.